Errno 110 Connection timed out in firebase admin python lambda
I'm trying to create a lambda python api that can send notification to a user device but I'm encountering Connection Timed Out error.
Also tried already to set the timeout in lambda to 1 minute but still the same.
What I did is installed firebase-admin via pip3 install firebase-admin in my local device and uploaded it as a layer.
this is my lambda-function.py
import json
import boto3
import asyncio
import time
import flogger

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging
from firebase_admin.exceptions import FirebaseError, InvalidArgumentError, InternalError

from os import environ
from traceback import format_exc
from config import ConfigClass

print('Loading function')
dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb')

stage = environ['STAGE']

initialized = False

def initialize_firebase_app():
    global initialized
    if not initialized:
        try:
            config = ConfigClass()
            result = asyncio.run(config.firebase_config())
            cred = credentials.Certificate(result['credential'])
            firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
            initialized = True
            flogger.log('debug', 'Firebase app initialized')
        except Exception as e:
            flogger.log('warning', f'Failed to initialize Firebase app: {e}')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Initialize Firebase app if not already initialized
    initialize_firebase_app()

    # List of registration tokens/fcm_token
    registration_tokens = [
        'fcmtoken1',
    ]
    
    # Define the notification payload
    notification = messaging.Notification(
        title='Test Notification',
        body='This is a test message notification.',
    )
    
    # Define the data payload
    data = {
        'id': '477',
        'firebase-uuid': json.dumps(['uuid1']),
        'type': 'type',
    }
    
    # Create a message with the notification and data payloads
    message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
        tokens=registration_tokens,
        notification=notification,
        data=data
    )
    
    # Function to send message with retries
    def send_message_with_retries(message, max_retries=5, initial_backoff=1):
        for attempt in range(max_retries):
            try:
                print('Sending message, attempt ', attempt + 1)
                response = messaging.send_multicast(message)
                print('Message sent successfully: ', response)
                return response
            except FirebaseError as e:
                print('Failed to send message: ', e)
                if attempt < max_retries - 1:
                    sleep_time = initial_backoff * (2 ** attempt)
                    print('Retrying seconds...', sleep_time)
                    time.sleep(sleep_time)
                else:
                    print('Max retries reached. Failed to send message.')
                    raise
    
    # Send the message
    print('sending message')
    send_message_with_retries(message)

and my config.py
import boto3

class ConfigClass:

    async def firebase_config(self):
        result = {}


        result['credential'] =  {
            "type": "service_account",
            "project_id": "my-mobile-app",
            "private_key_id": "my-private-key-id",
            "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\my-private-key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
            "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-j3mmmm6k@my-mobile-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
            "client_id": "my-client-id",
            "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
            "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-j3mmmm6k%40my-mobile-app.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
            "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
        }

        return result

Is there any configuration that I need to add?

which connection is timing out? to dynamo or to firebase?
are you running the lambda in a vpc?
do you get a url  that is timing out?

Got it! I have to remove the api from VPC. now works fine .
